# Record Prefix Missing

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm confused why the column headers are outputted differently for the following two queries.

`select fullVisitorId , visitNumber, visitId, visitStartTime, date,totals.visits, totals.hits, totals.pageviews, totals.timeOnSite 
from 33959632.ga_sessions_20170124`

First 7 columns are returned with the following names.

visitorId | visitNumber | visitId | visitStartTime | date | **totals.visits | totals.hits**

```
SELECT fullVisitorId , visitNumber, visitId, visitStartTime, date,   
totals.visits, totals.hits  FROM `33959632.ga_sessions_20170101`
```

Results below now have the **Total** record prefix removed.

fullVisitorId | visitNumber | visitId | visitStartTime | date | **visits | hits**

Why has Total been removed from Visits & Hits?  How can we keep the prefix name there in the results (besides manually naming the column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in GA - per schema - the `totals` field is not an array but rather just record
So, try below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  visitStartTime,
  date,
  STRUCT(totals.visits, totals.hits, totals.pageviews, totals.timeOnSite) AS totals
FROM `33959632.ga_sessions_20170101`
```

> Why has Total been removed from Visits & Hits?

In the SELECT list, if there is an expression that does not have an explicit alias, BigQuery assigns an implicit alias according to the following rules.

- For identifiers, the alias is the identifier. For example, SELECT abc implies AS abc.
- For path expressions, the alias is the last identifier in the path. For example, SELECT abc.def.ghi implies AS ghi.
- For field access using the "dot" member field access operator, the alias is the field name. For example, SELECT (struct_function()).fname implies AS fname.

You can read more about [Implicit aliases](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#implicit-aliases)

And you can read more about [Aliases](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#aliases_2) in general

Answer (score 1):

If you select a field path in standard SQL, the result will have the type of the leaf field in the path. If you want to produce a struct to mirror the original structure, you can do e.g.:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  visitStartTime,
  date,
  STRUCT(
    totals.visits,
    totals.hits,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.timeOnSite) AS totals
FROM 33959632.ga_sessions_20170124;
```

This returns the indicated fields of `totals` within a struct in the result.

Comment: My code above is in standard sql and I did uncheck the option to flatten results.  However it still removes the record prefix from everything.   Sounds like it is necessary to use the code that you suggested either way?  Thank you for your response!

Comment: Ah, I see. Mikhail ended up giving the same answer, but the basic idea is that if you want to preserve the shape of `totals` in the result, you should use the `STRUCT` operator. An alternative is just to select `totals` directly if you want to include all of its fields in the result.

Comment: :o) at a time when I answered - these were two different answers I think. but definitely same concept. agree